# How do I add a .jar file to the classpath on Mac OS X?

Tags: java

I'm starting to become pretty irritated, because EVERY time I try to add a JAR file to the classpath to run a program (which compiles fine in Eclipse) I get a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" exception.
The file swt.jar and GUI.class (main class) are in the same directory. If I issue this command: "java -cp swt.jar GUI", I get this error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: GUI Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GUI     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

If I formulate the command like this: "java GUI -cp swt.jar", it'll throw this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display   at GUI.main(GUI.java:9) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     ... 1 more

I just want to know how I can add .jar files to the runtime classpath on mac.
All of these commands are being issued from the Terminal on a 64-bit MacBook running Mac OS X Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, I think, is that you are specifying swt.jar as the classpath, but the file you're using is not in the jar. You neeed to specify both the jar and this dir as the classpath.

e.g.

`java -cp swt.jar:./ GUI`

Comment: Thanks, that really helped a lot :). Here's the exact command line option I used (that worked):"java -d32 -XstartOnFirstThread -cp swt.jar:. GUI"

Answer (score 0):

This one will work, with modifications:

> If I formulate the command like this: "java GUI -cp swt.jar"

You just didn't go far enough.  You have to add ALL the 3rd party JARs, including the ones for Eclipse SWT and all your other dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... in Eclipse the ONLY .jar file I've added to the build path is swt.jar, and it is the only .jar file I import classes from.

Comment: Eclipse is hiding stuff from you - it's doing things for you behind the scenes.  If you aren't going to use Eclipse, you have to understand and recreate what it's doing for you.